# Get SharePoint user's member of group list with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to get SpGroup list for a user's member of. And Powershell Gridview column not showing all info.

```
Get-SPUser -Web https://contonso.com -Limit all | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*tom"} |
select UserLogin, @{name="Groups";expression={$_.Groups}}
```

which returns;

```
UserLogin        Groups
---------        ------
i:0#.w|xyx\tom   {group1, group2, group3, group4...
```

is there any way to show group information like line by line?

```
UserLogin        Groups
---------        ------
i:0#.w|xyx\tom   group1
                 group2
                 group3
                 group4
                 group5
```

is there any way to achieve this with `| Out-GridView`  ?

i've also tried `format-Table -auto` and `Out-String -Width xxx` but the column is too big, even max int not working.

Comment: Try with `Select-Object UserLogin, @{name="Groups";expression={($_.Groups -join [environment]::NewLine)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap`  or pipe to `Out-GridView`

Comment: @Theo this worked well, thank you so much. Can you please write your answer so i can mark as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing how you want the output to lookk like, you need to join the items in array `$_.Groups` with newline characters.

To output on console you can then pipe the result to Format-Table adding the `-Wrap` switch:

```
Select-Object UserLogin, @{name="Groups";expression={($_.Groups -join [environment]::NewLine)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Or if you want to use the GridView, do

```
Select-Object UserLogin, @{name="Groups";expression={($_.Groups -join [environment]::NewLine)}} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but thank you so much for your help. That really works well.